# Sharing context data between parent and child tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I would like to share some context data that remains for the entire life of a thread/task that set that context data.

Looking at the pseudo code below, I have multiple tasks that all call asynchronous methods.
One way or another, they are all child tasks of the 'main', parent, task.

task1 would set context data that would be available to all the children of that task and task2 would do the same but all its children would have access to its data.

```
tasks (add) task1
               Set context data (value = "1")
               (await) -->  task1-B (await) -->  task1-C (await) -->  thread1-D --|
               |------------------------------------------------------------------|
               UnSet context data (value = null)

tasks (add) task2
               Set context data (value = "2")
               (await) -->  task2-B (await) -->  task2-C (await) -->  thread2-D --|
               |------------------------------------------------------------------|
               UnSet context data (value = null)

await tasks.WaitAll();
```

What I could do is pass the value from methods to methods, always insuring that the 'context' is passed.

The problem with that approach is that it would mean re-writing all the children methods, (the methods B, C, D in my example).

The other issue is that some methods are called by other method, for example, method E could call method C

```
task2-E (await) -->  task2-C (await) --|
|--------------------------------------|
```

In the case above the context might be set already, (re-entry somehow), or not be set at all.

I know a 'child' task cannot get it's parent task or a parent cannot get its children tasks, otherwise I could set some global list that would somehow keep track of all the contexts.

I was just wondering if it was possible to have a 'context' unique to as task and subtasks.

Comment: Why you can't pass to the async Task methods also the context class instance as a paramter?

Comment: Surely you're going to have to rewrite the child task methods anyway? Otherwise, how will they be able to access the context?

Comment: You *might* be able to use [the `CallContext` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext?view=netframework-4.8) to store and free logical data which would flow with the task's execution context - so long as you don't use `ConfigureAwait`. But the methods you're calling would still need to be updated to retrieve the context data from this class.

Comment: @FedericoAlterio as I mentioned, there are a lot of async calls all over the place, I don't want to update all the methods.

Comment: @RichardDeeming no, in my example I would only rewrite the "parent" method, (to set the context), and the one method that needs the information. None of the others would change.

Comment: @RichardDeeming CallContext is only for the _current_ thread/task, as soon as I move to another task, (even a task I am awaiting on), I look that context information.

Comment: @FFMG Are you sure about that? In ASP.NET, `HttpContext.Current` is implemented using the `CallContext`, and that manages to survive across `await` boundaries (so long as you don't use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`).

Comment: @FFMG You need to use `LogicalGetData` and `LogicalSetData` for the data to flow with the tasks, as [Stephen Cleary explains](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).

Comment: @RichardDeeming thanks a lot, that did the trick, I need to test performance.
Please add it as a reply so I can comment on my perf results and mark it as a solution!

Comment: @FFMG I think Stephen's already covered it nicely in his answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-6.0). A couple of
[`AsyncLocal<T>` caveats from my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html):

1. It should be set in an `async` method, because that triggers the "copy on write" behavior of the logical thread context.
2. You should only store immutable data.

Generally, the code I use ends up looking something like this:

```
internal static class MyAsyncContext
{
  // string is immutable
  private static AsyncLocal<string> _asyncLocal = new();

  // this should ONLY be called from an async method
  public IDisposable Set(string value)
  {
    var previous = _asyncLocal.Value;
    _asyncLocal.Value = value;
    return Disposable.Create(() => _asyncLocal.Value = previous);
  }

  public string? TryGet() => _asyncLocal.Value;
}
```

(this is using a `Disposable` helper from my [Disposables library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Disposables))

Usage in parent method:

```
async Task task1()
{
  using var context = MyAsyncContext.Set("1");
  await task1B();
}
```

Usage in child method:

```
async Task task1D()
{
  var contextData = MyAsyncContext.TryGet();
}
```